# <del> in code block

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, design

Is there any way to use `<del>` *inside* a formatted code block, or *around* the whole code block? I would like to emphesize that that code snippet is *NOT* the way to go, or use the traditional instead <del>this code</del> use `this code` logic.

It is only one line of code, so I can create almost the same layout using inline formatting around the code, but block formatting would be much nicer.

(Ps: I know `del` is an inline element but hey, here comes HTML5. Tag soup is in season again. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)

Comment: Please don't do this in a code block. That's the whole point of a code block. Leave your diffs to your code repository.

Comment: @Cody I can imagine legitimate uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DEL
```

```
<pre><code><del>DEL</del></code></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I have not tried `<pre>`.